# Putting bounds on stochastic variables in PyMC

Tags: python, pymc

I have a variable `A` which is Bernoulli distributed, `A = pymc.Bernoulli('A', p_A)`, but I don't have a hard value for `p_A` and want to sample for it. I do know that it should be small, so I want to use an exponential distribution `p_A = pymc.Exponential('p_A', 10)`.

However, the exponential distribution can return values higher than 1, which would throw off `A`. Is there a way of bounding the output of `p_A` without having to re-implement either the Bernoulli or the Exponential distributions in my own `@pymc.stochastic`-decorated function?

Comment: My first attempt has been to approximate the exponential distribution using a Beta distribution, `a = 1`, `b > 1`. You can also sort of approximate a bounded Poisson distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyMC provides bounds. The following should also work:

```
p_A = pymc.Bound(pymc.Exponential, upper=1)('p_A', lam=10)
```

Comment: As of PyMC 4.0, the syntax for pymc.Bound has changed. The order of the arguments is a bit different now — you should use `pymc.Bound('p_A', pymc.Exponential.dist(lam=10), upper=1)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use a deterministic function to truncate the Exponential distribution. Personally I believe it would be better if you use a distribution that is bound between 0 and 1, but to exactly solve your problem you can do as follows:

```
import pymc as pm
p_A = pm.Exponential('p_A',10)

@pm.deterministic
def p_B(p=p_A):
    return min(1, p)

A = pm.Bernoulli('A', p_B)

model = dict(p_A=p_A, p_B=p_B, A=A)
S = pm.MCMC(model)
S.sample(1000)
p_B_trace = S.trace('p_B')[:]
```

Answer (score 0):

For any other lost souls who come across this:

I think the best solution for my purposes (that is, I was only using the exponential distribution because the probabilities I was looking to generate were *probably small*, rather than out of mathematical convenience) was to use a Beta function instead.

For [certain parameter values](http://mathlets.org/mathlets/beta-distribution/) it approximates the shape of an exponential function (and can do the same for binomials and normals), but is bounded to [0 1]. Probably only useful for doing things numerically, though, as I imagine it's a pain to do any analysis with.